# Firebase messages with special characters

Tags: android, character-encoding, firebase-cloud-messaging, urlencode

I'm trying to send a message using Firebase cloud messaging with special characters, like Russian language characters. Here the relevant code:

From app sender:

```
String message = tv.getText().toString(); //get text from UI text view
....
App myapp = new App.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(getString(R.string.app_name)).build();
try {
     //send the message to the server
     myapp.sendToGroup(new String(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
          StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
     return;
}
```

From the server:

```
    Map<String, JsonElement> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
    dataMap.put(MSG, new JsonPrimitive(message));
    pushMessage.setData(dataMap);

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    URL url = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("project_id", "xxxxxxx");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + FCM_API_KEY);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    .......//send the request here
```

App receiver service:

```
public class CloudListenerService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
    String message = data.get(MSG);
    if (message == null)
        return;
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    Intent r = getNewIntent();
    b.putString(Receiver.EXTRA_MESSAGE, new String(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    sendBroadcast(r);
}
}
```

The message I see is ?????? it just means there's something wrong with encoding. From the server I can see the right string encoded with %23clip%23%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80 (i.e. #clip#пример the text I sent). Where's the error?

Comment: Do you receive "%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80" in data.get(MSG) in your CloudListenerService?

Comment: How do you display the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem found: I was creating the writer in a wrong way. I changed the code from

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
```

to

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
```